# C++ Undefined Reference

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ “ undefined reference to 'Foo::Foo(std::string)' ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656050/c-undefined-reference-to-foofoostdstring)

I got three `.cpp` files and `two header files.`

But when i compile them, meaning the `Point.cpp`, `Data.cpp` and `main.cpp`, it will say

```
main.cpp: undefined reference to "PointD::PointD()' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Below is my `Data.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Data
{
    private:
    string sType;
    public:
    Data();
    Data(string);
    void setSType(string);
    string getSType(); 
};
```

Below is my `data.cpp`:

```
#include "Data.h"

Data::Data()
{
    sType = "";
}

Data::Data(string s)
{
    sType = s;
}

void Data::setSType(string ss)
{
    sType = ss;
}

string Data::getSType()
{
    return sType;
}
```

Below is my `PointD.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Data.h"

using namespace std;

class PointD
{
    private:
    int x
    Data data1;
    public:
    PointD();
    PointD(int,Data);

    void setX(int);
    void setData(Data);

    int getX();
    Data getData();
};
```

Below is my `PointD.cpp`:

```
#include "PointD.h"

PointD::PointD()
{
    x = 0;
}

PointD::PointD(int xOrdinate,Data dd)
{
    x = xOrdinate;
    data1 = dd;
}

void PointD::setXordinate(int Xordinate)
{
    x = Xordinate;
}

void PointD::setData(Data dd)
{
    data1 = dd;
};

int PointD::getXordinate()
{
    return x;
}

Data PointD::getData()
{
    return data1;
}
```

This is my `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Data.h"
#include "PointD.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MAX_NUM = 20;

    Data ldata[MAX_NUM];
    PointD pointd[MAX_NUM];

    //more codes..
}
```

But when I compile them, meaning the `Point.cpp`, `Data.cpp` and `main.cpp`, it will say

main.cpp: undefined reference to "PointD::PointD()' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: What is the command you use to compile? My guess is that the command asks to build an executable out of 'Data.cpp' instead of all the sources / object files.

Comment: Are you sure the error occurred in Data.cpp? Because nowhere in Data.cpp do you use the PointD class.

Answer (score 3):

You are likely trying to compile and link main.cpp, without PointD.cpp or data.cpp. Try to add all the sources to the command, or **compile only** all the sources before linking them together.

Comment: You got it right, i missed the file haha.

Answer (score 1):

The error is being thrown because g++ could not find the required dependency of the PointD and Data definitions. Hence, classes these becomes undefined references.

use the following command to compile so that main will be able to find the class defintions

```
   g++ main.cpp Data.cpp PointD.cpp -o main
```

Also, remove the statement

```
  #include "Data.h"
```

from your main.cpp; otherwise it will find the class definition twice.

Additionally, you'll have to add

```
   int getXordinate();
   void setXordinate(int Xordinate);
```

to your PointD.h for error free compilation.

Hope this helps!